# Dynamic website change after few buttons clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html

First of all I am very new at this so sorry in advance if I say something stupid.

The idea is very simple: lets say I have a website with bunch of buttons. User click some buttons and underneath them some text appears. If user clicks wrong buttons text disappears on another text appears instead.

I could do this using PHP with POST and some forms, but it reloads the whole page, that I do not like. And if after submitting I refresh the page I get annoying message "The page that you're looking for used information that you entered. Returning to that mage might cause any action you took to be repeated.", I'd like to return to default text after refreshing without any messages.

To make things simple and clear, I'll give an example: lets say I have 6 buttons on my website, named 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6, and text underneath would list last 3 buttons clicked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button">1</button>
    <button type="button">2</button>
    <button type="button">3</button>
    <button type="button">4</button>
    <button type="button">5</button>
    <button type="button">6</button>
    <br/>
    <p>Last 3 buttons clicked: none</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Lets say user clicks buttons 1, 2 and 3, then text changes to "Last 3 buttons clicked: 1, 2, 3", after that user clicks 3 again and now text says "Last 3 buttons clicked: 2, 3, 3".

Even greater would be if after clicking specific 3 buttons all the buttons would disappear and "Victory!" text would be shown instead of them.

Something like a door lock code.

So, could someone please give me an example of how to get my desired result?

Comment: You might wanna look into AJAX, but apart from  that I'm not sure what your question is, or rather, your current question seem to be very broad.

Comment: Yeah, I am more like asking for help than asking a specific question, I am that bad at web programming :(

Comment: @Cigaras, How does your JS look like ?

Comment: I have no JS at this point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array `push()` and `shift()` to add an element at the end of an array and remove first element, respectively.

So you could keep track of your pushed element with handling an array with size `<=` 3.

The correct code for this snippet is `4 3 2`.

```js
// add event listeners
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    digicode(this);
  });
}

// the array holding last 3 codes
var codes = [];

// handling the array
var digicode = function(element) {
  codes.push(parseInt(element.innerHTML));
  if (codes.length > 3) codes.shift();
  var codes_tmp = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
    codes_tmp += codes[i] + " ";
  }
  document.getElementById("clicked").innerHTML = codes_tmp;

  // handling "victory"
  if (codes[0] !== undefined && codes[0] == 4 &&
    codes[1] !== undefined && codes[1] == 3 &&
    codes[2] !== undefined && codes[2] == 2) {
    document.body.innerHTML = "";
    alert("Victory!");
  }
  console.log(codes);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button">1</button>
  <button type="button">2</button>
  <button type="button">3</button>
  <button type="button">4</button>
  <button type="button">5</button>
  <button type="button">6</button>
  <br/>
  <p>Last 3 buttons clicked: <span id="clicked">none</span>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by `AJAX`. Here I'm giving minimal example of `jQuery` with `AJAX`. This is not a complete solution. You'll have to change code according to your requirement. You may refer to [jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/) and [jQuery with AJAX](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/) here.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <button type="button">1</button>
    <button type="button">2</button>
    <button type="button">3</button>
    <button type="button">4</button>
    <button type="button">5</button>
    <button type="button">6</button>
    <br/>
    <p>Last 3 buttons clicked: <span id="clicked"></span></p>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

      $("button").on("click", function(){

       /* You need to write your logic accordingly */

       var val = $("#clicked").text()+","+$(this).text();

        $("#clicked").text(val)

    //Update to Server using AJAX

        $.ajax({
          url: "YourFileOnServer.php",
          data: {val: val},
          type: "post",
          success: function(data){
                  //Response from your Server
          }
        });

      });

    });

</script>   

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with plain JavaScript (but it might not be the best way)

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="button1()">1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="button2()">2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="button3()">3</button>
<button type="button" onclick="button4()">4</button>
<button type="button" onclick="button5()">5</button>
<button type="button" onclick="button6()">6</button>
<br/>
<p id="lastClicked">Last 3 buttons clicked: none</p>
<p hidden id="lastClicked1"></p>
<p hidden id="lastClicked2"></p>
<p hidden id="lastClicked3"></p>
<script src="button.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function button1() {
lastClicked1 = document.getElementById("lastClicked1").innerHTML;
lastClicked2 = document.getElementById("lastClicked2").innerHTML;
lastClicked3 = document.getElementById("lastClicked3").innerHTML;

document.getElementById("lastClicked1").innerHTML = lastClicked2;
document.getElementById("lastClicked2").innerHTML = lastClicked3;
document.getElementById("lastClicked3").innerHTML = "1";

lastClicked1 = document.getElementById("lastClicked1").innerHTML;
lastClicked2 = document.getElementById("lastClicked2").innerHTML;
lastClicked3 = document.getElementById("lastClicked3").innerHTML;

document.getElementById("lastClicked").innerHTML = "Last 3 buttons clicked: " + lastClicked1 + ", " + lastClicked2 + ", " + lastClicked3;

}
```

Just repeat that 6 times replacing the 1s with whatever button number it is. I know it's a pretty long way around and there is probably a way to simplify this but I'm pretty new to this too.

For the victory message just add in an if statement to check if    lastClicked == whatever 3 numbers you want.